# Need a script to open ssh connections

Tags: shell, ssh

My entirely new to MAC OS.
I am using MAC Terminal to connect to Linux servers (using SSH)

Is there a way to write a .command file to connect to the Linux servers, just by executing the .bat file from desktop?

Comment: How would a shell script be simpler than `ssh remotehost`?  This question belongs on [su]

Comment: i would just need to add the server IP , User name , Passwords - So when i execute the .command - I would be directed to server

Comment: It seems that 'What you really want is a launcher/desktop shortcut'...

Answer (score 1):

Look at ssh client configuration and key-based authentication (`man ssh` and `man ssh_config`). You can configure all that so the command reduces to `ssh hostname` without writing any shellscript code.  You can even assign a short name to a host.

For example (in `~/.ssh/config`):

```
host abc
hostname remotehost.domain.tld
identityfile ~/.ssh/abc.dsa
user myuserid
```

Assuming you've generated and uploaded the corresponding public key, you can connect with the command

```
ssh abc
```

Comment: +1 This completely obviates the need for a separate script file.  If, however, you should still want one, create a Bash script like `/home/you/bin/linux` with contents like `ssh yourusername@10.11.12.13` and mark it executable.  For more details, see e.g. http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php … but I would sternly recommend to set up the proper SSH settings in your `.ssh/config` file in any event, first and foremost.